# Spongy / soft feeling brakes on brand new car

Tags: brakes

Just got a 2019 CX-5, brand new. Brakes feel spongy, like you need to apply a lot of pressure to them. Almost felt like I had a hard time planning my stops to get the car to stop exactly at the stop line.
At least comparing to my other car I drive, which is a Hyundai. Wife also says brakes feel bad, compared to her previous car which was a 2016 Mazda.
Car is brand new, has 300 miles on it.
Any ideas what could be wrong? Dealer says the brakes are fine and they run soft on the new Mazdas.

Comment: Take it to a different dealer and get them to check it.

Comment: Thanks. What are some of the things that could be wrong, considering this is a brand new car?

Comment: Could be many things, but you cannot touch them as it is under warranty, so take it to a dealer...

Comment: Brakes in different brand/model cars feel different from each other - it could be normal.  I switch between four relatively new vehicles (F-150,  Sienna, Jetta, X3) and I generally have to get used the car for the first couple of stops.  
But get them checked.

Comment: I say hydraulics or the brake booster is probably whack. Please take to another dealer and report that dealership to corporate